# unsatisfied dependencyexception in spring java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have created a sample application in spring to insertdata the normal way i used to do but this time it is giving exception like unsatisfied bean exception.
The projects i created this way are all running normally but new projects are not running in any of my systems.

MyController

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import com.Service.MyService;
  @Controller
     public class MyController {

MyService serv;
@Autowired
public void setserv(MyService ms)
{
    ms=serv;
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String vi()
  {
return "first";
  }

@RequestMapping("/get")
  public String vii(userdata ud)
   {
    serv.insertdata(ud);
return "first";
 }

}
```

MyService

```
 package com.Service;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

 import com.controller.userdata;
 import com.dao.MyDao;

@Service
  public class MyService {
     MyDao dao;
   @Autowired
  public void setdao(MyDao dao)
   {
       this.dao=dao;
   }
 public void insertdata(userdata ud) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   dao.insertdata(ud);
  }
  }
```

MyDAo

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource;
 import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   import com.controller.userdata;

  @Component
 public class MyDao {
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc)
{
    this.jdbc=new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);

}
public void insertdata(userdata ud) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource par=new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(ud);
    jdbc.update("insert into insertdata value(:fn,:ln)",par);
}
}
```

My Ds-servlet

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.controller">
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="ViewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsppages/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Console

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setserv' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [com.Service.MyService] found for dependency [com.Service.MyService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.Service.MyService] found for dependency [com.Service.MyService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:648)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:858)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.Service.MyService] found for dependency [com.Service.MyService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
... 36 more

 Nov 21, 2017 2:56:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
```

Do say what should i do

Comment: `ms=serv;` should be `this.serv = ms;`

Comment: In your controller there is a mistake in assigning. Use `this.serv = ms;`.

Comment: it didn't solve